# I need a regex to validate phone numbers which contains only 0 or 1 as invalid

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I need a regex to validate only 0s or 1s in a phone number. For eg - 0000000000 or 1111111111 should be invalid.
Also my phone number range is from 7-15 only. Below is my regex [0-9]{7,15}
it should add validation in the regex to invalidate only 0 and only 1 in the phone number

Comment: Please add the code/regex you've attempted to your question as a [mcve].  What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? [Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) - [https://regex101.com/](https://regex101.com/) for testing. Note that different languages have different regex implementations so you should be clear what language you're asking about.

Answer (score 0):

This regex will match the phone numbers with 0s and 1s

`/([01*]{10})/gm`

Answer (score 0):

Regex pattern for 1s and 0s only

```
^[0-1]+$
```

**HTML EXAMPLE**

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" pattern="^[0-1]+$" title="Invalid input">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```